# Regex issue - Matching API name

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am currently working with a large code base, in which recently one of the API's signature changed. So I need to modify thousands of files to get the new feature. So developed a java program to get take all `*.java` files and look for old API pattern. If found replace it with new pattern.

#### Old API

```
API(3,Utils.FIFTY,key1,key4)
```

#### New API

```
API(key1,key4)
```

So I created a regex pattern to match the old API as `API\([\d,\s\.\w]*(key[\.\w\s,]*)\)`
If it matches it will replace it with

`replaceString = matcher.group(1) + "(" + matcher.group(2) + ")";`

So with the current code instead of expected `API(key1,key4)`, I am getting `API(key4)`. I've analyzed the issue and my inference is that the `\w` caught the first **key** pattern. If we need to match, we need to do a negative look ahead.

Can any one share the best consistent way to resolve the regex issue ?

Comment: Why not `@deprecate` the `API(3,Utils.FIFTY,key1,key4)` form, call the new form internally, and recompile?

Comment: The API is developed by another team and we don't have access to it. The API still exists for backward compatibility. Since we need the new feature, we need to call the new method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
API\([\.\w \t,]*?,\s*(key[\.\w \t,]*)\)
```

The main change here was to change the repetition on the first character class from `*` to `*?`, this means it will now match as few characters as possible instead of as many as possible, so you all of your `key` arguments will be included in your matching group.

Comment: What about line feed between `(` and `)`?

Comment: @Aubin I replaced the `\s` so the character classes will match spaces and tabs but not line feeds, good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The F.J's answer doesn't match this test case:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class APIUpdater {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String source = "\n" +
        "API( key.getValue( 18 ),call( key1 ).mth(),key1,key4);\n" +
        "API(\n" +
        "\t3,\n" +
        "\tUtils.FIFTY,\n" +
        "\tkey1,\n" +
        "\tkey4 );\n" +
        "API(3,Utils.FIFTY,key1,key4);\n";
      Pattern p =
         Pattern.compile( "API\\([.\\w\\s,]*?,\\s*(key[\\.\\w\\s,]*)\\)" );
      Matcher m = p.matcher( source );
      while( m.find())
      {
         System.err.println( m.replaceAll( "API(key1,key4)" ));
      }
   }
}
```

Output is:

```
API( key.getValue( 18 ),call( key1 ).mth(),key1,key4);
API(key1,key4);
API(key1,key4);
```

A call on several lines doesn't match but spaces are correctly handled.

A true parser with a grammar is required to parse Java, a regular expressions can't do this complex job because they works at lexical level (the words, not the sentences).

Comment: I don't have complex scenarios like the first example you mentioned. But the second and third samples are valid for me, means the API can be broken in to multiple lines due to code formatting. Such cases the the reluctant quantifier approach(_*?_) works fine. We have already incorporated **\s** for the whitespace chanracters.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Recoder](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/recoder/index.php?title=Writing_transformations), which allows you to apply source code transformations.

Comment: +1: this solution tackle the problem at correct abstraction level

Comment: I liked the Recorder pattern and will have try.